# How can I start production with webpack?

Tags: webpack, production-environment

So far I've been developing with express, react, webpack and socket io on development side, but I wanna start to work on the production site. What modules shold I get? I also would appreciate any set up source for production, ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to suggest what changes you need to make to prepare your app for production without knowing exactly what you're currently doing in development however a few things to consider include:

- Serve static files -- If you're using `webpack-dev-server` or `webpack-dev-middleware` during development you'll want to make sure you instead bundle and serve static files for production using the regular [webpack cli](https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html).
- Minify bundle -- This can be done by passing [`-p`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html#production-shortcut-p) to the webpack cli or by adding the [`UglifyJsPlugin`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin) to your config.
- Revision assets -- This will allow you to take advantage of [long term browser caching](https://webpack.github.io/docs/long-term-caching.html).

You might like to take a look at the [60fram.es boilerplate](https://github.com/60frames/react-boilerplate) which includes both development and production builds.